# Given a finite set of size n, how many different topologies are admissible in terms of n?

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Up to symmetry or not. For example, it would help to clarify whether in a certain "formula", for example, the topologies { {a, b, c}, {a}, O } and { {a, b, c}, {b}, O} on {a, b, c} are both counted.

n.b.:

A topology on a set is a set of open subsets of a set such that:

1. The empty set and the full set are open,
2. Union of open sets (finite or infinite) is open,
3. Finite intersection of open sets is open.

Comment: This is a pretty tough problem.  You can start here:  http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/FINITE/REUNotes2010/FiniteSpaces.pdf

Comment: I think the general case is open.

Comment: The Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences has pages for both the number of topologies on a labeled set or on an unlabeled set (so up to symmetry). Here are the pages: [labeled](https://oeis.org/A000798) and [unlabeled](https://oeis.org/A001930).

Comment: Hey Randall, this is off topic, but you kind of posted a link to an REU that I'm very interested in. I don't know if you can help me, but would I be able to ask you some questions about that REU (specifically whether it's right for me)?

Comment: just to be clear, that OEIS sequence starts from 1 or 0? (It seems like the empty set has the trivial topology)

Comment: @MarcusAurelius   I am unqualified to give much feedback about that REU.  I've worked in the same area, but that's the extent.  Knowing Peter, I know it's (a) likely amazing and (b) super-competitive.